# Crashlytics (Fabric) without plugin

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, crashlytics

How can I use Crashlytics(Fabric) for project without installing of plugin for AndroidStudio, using only Gradle on my build server?
I tried to find any instructions for that, but without result.

I have this code in my project:

**Project build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        ...

    }
    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
```

**Module build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "io.fabric"

repositories {
    ...
    maven { url "https://maven.fabric.io/public" }
}
...
dependencies {
    ...
    compile("com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.4.0@aar") { transitive = true }
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<meta-data android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey" android:value="..." />
```

**Application**

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
    ...
}
```

I had this file in eclipse project - "crashlytics.properties" (with apiSecret). Should I use it somewhere in AndroidStudio and Gradle?

Also, Should I add some other information in the project to add Crashlytics correctly?

Comment: At least the API key. You are missing that somewhere?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I added apiKey in manifest <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="..." />

Comment: I had this file in eclipse project - "crashlytics.properties" (with apiSecret). Should I use it somewhere in AndroidStudio?

Comment: Yes, inside the src folder. But why don't you install the plugin? I have it and everything works smooth.

Comment: I need it without any plugins, using only clear gradle. Reason - build server.

Comment: Once you set up the project with plugin, you can build it everywhere. i.e. plugin is not required for build.

Comment: Where crashlytics.properties used in gradle file after installing of plugin? Can you show me that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer here http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/202140-do-you-support-build-tools-for-android
and here https://fabric.io/downloads/gradle